# Javascript incrementer mysteriously jumps in value

Tags: javascript

I have code that runs through a loop, and does some work a child of a certain id of a section. So to help myself, I made a little function to grab the child:

```
function GetChildTagById(par,tag,id){
    var divs = par.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    for(i=0;i<divs.length;i++){
        if(divs[i].id==id){
            return divs[i];
        }
    }
}
```

and did some work on it:

```
var bar = new Array();
for(i=0;i<somelist.length;i++){
    var foo =GetChildTagById(group,'div',id[i]);
    DoWork(foo);
    bar[i] = foo;
}
```

but later when I try to access the array it states that the elements don't exist. When I looked at the array in the log, it had values for 0 and for 177, and nothing in between. What could cause this?

Comment: Now you will realize you need to use `var` and that it is not really optional. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some how the closures of the `i` variable don't do what is expected. The issue can be fixed by typing `var i=0` in the for loop rather than `i=0`.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.

Comment: Both loops are modifying the same global variable `i`.

Comment: When you call the `GetChildTagById`, it changes the `i` variable being used by your main loop.

Comment: You should always use local variables unless you have a specific reason to use a global variable.

Comment: Yeah I thought the `var` was optional, and that I was using local variables, so it took me a bit to figure out what was going on.